# ERROR en sencia preparada con operador BETWEEEN

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo la siguiente sentencia PDO pero me dice que tengo error de sintaxis, me funciona sin operador between pero cuando agrego el operador deja de funcionar, comento que estoy haciendo referencia a MySQL
¿Cúal es la manera correcta del código?

```
try{
    $conexion_base_datos = new BaseDatosPayboard();
    
    $consulta_saldo_agente = $conexion_base_datos -> conexionBaseDatos() -> prepare("SELECT 
    SUM(montoPago) AS total_cobrado_agente FROM bujic_payboard.pagos WHERE registroAgente <=> 
    :usuario_registro AND fechaPago BETWEEN <=> :fecha_inicial_agente AND <=> 
    :fecha_final_agente");
            
    $consulta_saldo_agente -> execute(['usuario_registro' => $usuario_registro, 
    'fecha_inicial_agente' => $fecha_inicial_agente, 'fecha_final_agente' => 
    $fecha_final_agente]);
            
    $fila_consulta_agente = $consulta_saldo_agente -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
   
    echo json_encode($fila_consulta_agente['total_cobrado_agente']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ocurrió un problema al consultar y listar la información del cliente, error: " . 
    $e>getMessage();
}
```

¿Debo usarlo con bind_value o bind_param? ¡Ayuda!

Comment: ¿Existe el operador `<=>`? De ser así, ¿qué hace? Y por último, ¿por qué estás agregando ese operador?

Comment: Corrijo mi pregunta inicial porque veo que [en PHP sí existe](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): ¿Existe el operador `<=>` **en SQL**? (De hecho, omitiste a qué base de datos haces referencia (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.))

Comment: El operador <=> es equivalente al operador SQL estándar NO ES DISTINTO DE

Comment: Es un [`NULL-Safe Equal`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to). De todas maneras: ¿por qué querrías usar ese operador con un `BETWEEN`? ¿Revisaste [su sintaxis](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)?

Comment: En MySQL, el formato correcto es `columna BETWEEN valor1 AND valor2`, prueba quitando esos `<==>` y debe funcionar sin problema. El error es por usar dos operadores juntos.

Comment: Como dice el buen @Triby en base a la sintaxis cambia tu linea de esta manera y checa el resultado--> "  fechaPago BETWEEN fecha_inicial_agente  AND fecha_final_agente "

Comment: Quite los operadores <=> pero me marca el error:
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND fechaPago BETWEEN ? AND <=> ?' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando por varios sitios en internet, tomando en cuenta las respuestas que me brindaron, llegue a la solución de la siguiente manera:

```
try{
            $conexion_base_datos = new BaseDatosPayboard();
            $consulta_saldo_agente = $conexion_base_datos -> conexionBaseDatos() -> prepare("SELECT SUM(montoPago) AS total_cobrado_agente FROM pagos WHERE registroAgente =
            :usuario_registro AND fechaPago BETWEEN :fecha_inicial_agente AND :fecha_final_agente");
            $consulta_saldo_agente -> bindParam(':usuario_registro', $usuario_registro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $consulta_saldo_agente -> bindParam(':fecha_inicial_agente', $fecha_inicial_agente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $consulta_saldo_agente -> bindParam(':fecha_final_agente', $fecha_final_agente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $consulta_saldo_agente -> execute();
            $fila_consulta_agente = $consulta_saldo_agente -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
            echo json_encode($fila_consulta_agente['total_cobrado_agente']);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Ocurrió un problema al consultar y sumar la cantidad recuperada del agente, error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```